# Why the Broadcastreceiver dosen't receive the intents if the receiver and the filter dosen't set in the manifest?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, proximity

Why the Broadcastreceiver dosen't receive the intents if the receiver and the filter dosen't set in the manifest?

Working 1:

```
locationNotific = new Intent(PROXIMITY_STRING);

    lPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, locationNotific, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


       filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_STRING); 

     contextOnCreate.registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

    lm.addProximityAlert(LatitudeE6ForPeox1,LongitudeE6ForPeox1,POINT_RADIUS,-1,lPendingIntent);
```

In the manifest 1:

```
<receiver android:name=".ProximityIntentReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action  android:name="SendProximityIntent">
</action>           
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Working 2:

```
filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_STRING); 

         contextOnCreate.registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

          sendBroadcast(locationNotific);//working becouse of that (dosent work just with proximity)
```

**Dosent Working:**

```
    identif=Long.toString(id);
    locationNotific = new Intent(PROXIMITY_STRING + identif);

    lPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, locationNotific, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);



       filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_STRING + identif); 

     contextOnCreate.registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

    lm.addProximityAlert(LatitudeE6ForPeox1,LongitudeE6ForPeox1,POINT_RADIUS,-1,lPendingIntent);
```